# removing all traces of edubuntu from my ubuntu install

Tags: 12.04, edubuntu

Hi I installed edubuntu desktop on ubuntu and have decided to get rid of it. There is no problem with the function of my desktop but i would like to know why after removing edubuntu there is still traces remaining. Examples include dash symbol is edubuntu and all of the wallpaper selections remain. Any one know how to completely remove edubuntu? 
Like I said there is no problem with function just would like to know if there is a way I could get back to what i had before . thank you for your time.

Comment: To remove all this, you have to remove the .desktop files related to that application only.

Answer (score 0):

The chances are the Edubuntu Gear would have overwritten the base Ubuntu desktop.
You can try reinstalling UNITY or UBUNTU-DESKTOP to see if it will overwrite the edubuntu stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `sudo apt-get remove --purge edubuntu*` it should remove all the packages, configuration files and artwork.

Run `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove any other packages that are no longer needed.

If some artwork or appearance settings are still different, you can try installing the Unity Tweak Tool package (`sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`) to change the settings back to how they were before Edubuntu was installed.